# how can i get trusted user list from AD

Tags: c#

"Sam" is a user of **domain1.com**. send the user creditials and get the user information from AD

“tuser1” is a user of **domain2.com**.

domain1.com and domain2.com are two way trusted.

My question is:

1. How can i validate the "tuser1" is a valid user?.
2. How can I get the user information via domain1.com.

Comment: You can store the Session information in database and then shared the information between two domains. follow this link to know more about SQL server Mode sessions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.80).aspx